# Sign in with different account returns error page

Tags: powershell, authentication, sharepoint-online

I have 2 SPO sites, siteA.sharepoint.com and siteB.sharepoint.com. I have different account on each site.

When I login to 1 site (siteA), then open the other site (siteB) on the same browser, the following screen is shown which is expected (doesn't matter which site is logged in first)

[image]

However, clicking on the link "Click here to sign in with a different account to this site." shows an error page and the URL is appended with the following `_layouts/15/accessdenied.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true&Source=%2F`
[image: error after clicking link]

I notice this error recently because when I tested the login previously (a few months ago, maybe), I was presented with a screen to choose which Microsoft account to login after clicking the "Click here to sign in with a different account to this site." link.

Clearing the browser's cookies and cache allows me to login to any of the sites again without problem. However, this error impacts my Powershell code when I use `Connect-PnPOnline -Url mysiteurl -UseWebLogin`

Comment: have you tried logging in with credentials stored in the Windows Credentials Manager?

Comment: @teylyn no I haven't because I use web authentication which doesn't store credentials in the Credential Manager

Comment: That was kind of my point. i.e. don't use web authentication.

Comment: @teylyn I have to because Multi Factor Authentication is enabled, only web authentication flow works